# ¿A que se debe el error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java" en java?

Tags: java, netbeans, math

Estoy empezando en Java y se me solicito hacer el siguiente programa: "Un programa que calcule el cuadrado de una suma: (a+b)2 = a2 + b2 + 2ab" Al momento de realizarlo me ejecutó bien, el prpblema viene cuando introduzco el último dato, aquí el código:

```
package ejercicios;         //By console!

// @author Francisco Cruz
import java.math; //Importing math pack
import java.util.Scanner; //Importing Scanner for data by console

public class Ejercicio6 {
     public static void main(String[] args){
         Scanner enter = new Scanner(System.in); //System.in to get data

         double a,b,result; //Variables

         System.out.println("Introduce el valor de 'a': ");
            a = enter.nextFloat();
         System.out.println("Introduce el valor de 'b': ");
            b = enter.nextFloat();

            result =   math.pow(a,2) + math.pow(b,2) + (2*a*b); //Math process

            System.out.println("El resultado de la suma es:"+result); //Print result
     }
}
```

Comment: El paquete que creaste no se puede llamar `Java`.

Comment: Cuál es el error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

la clase math es con la M mayúscula.

Quedaría `Math.pow()`

Comment: Rayos, que error tan obvio y no me dí cuenta... Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

La clase `java.math` no existe, quizás quisiste utilizar `Math` con mayúscula, que no necesita importarse.